# jQuery .on(click) function containing IF statement checking for .hasClass() always returning true when it does not contain the class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, if-statement

I have been battling a dodgy IF that keeps returning a true value although the class it is checking for is not present on page load.

I am trying to add the class if it is not there, then remove the class when it is there.

The console.logs show it is correctly grabbing the attributes for popular-value & full, successfully logging these in their respective console.logs. However, the IF always console.logs 'has class'.

Here is the function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".popular-tag", function(){
    var popularTag = $(this);
    var popularTagSlug = popularTag.attr('popular-value');
    console.log(popularTagSlug);
    var popularTagName = popularTag.attr('popular-full');
    console.log(popularTagName);

    if (popularTag.hasClass('selected')) {
        console.log('has class');
        popularTag.removeClass('selected');
        popularTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
        popularTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
        popularTag.removeAttr('data-name');
    } else {
        console.log('doesnt have class');
        popularTag.addClass('selected');
        popularTag.addClass('selected-tag');
        popularTag.attr('data-slug', popularTagSlug);
        popularTag.attr('data-name', popularTagName);
    }
});
```

Here Is the HTML is it playing with (BEFORE CLICK):

```
<div class="popular-tags-selection">

    <div class="popular-tags-selection-title">
        Popular properties
    </div>

    <div id="popular-tags" class="popular-tags">

        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="aesthetic" popular-full="Aesthetic"><div class="popular-tag-title">Aesthetic</div></div>
        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="corrosion-resistant" popular-full="Corrosion resistant"><div class="popular-tag-title">Corrosion resistant</div></div>
        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="hard" popular-full="Hard"><div class="popular-tag-title">Hard</div></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the same code (AFTER CLICK):

```
<div class="popular-tags-selection">

    <div class="popular-tags-selection-title">
        Popular properties
    </div>

    <div id="popular-tags" class="popular-tags">

        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="aesthetic" popular-full="Aesthetic"><div class="popular-tag-title">Aesthetic</div></div>
        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="corrosion-resistant" popular-full="Corrosion resistant"><div class="popular-tag-title">Corrosion resistant</div></div>
        <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="hard" popular-full="Hard"><div class="popular-tag-title">Hard</div></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the console after the two clicks:

```
11:55:17.801 ready-functions.js?200226115513:448 aesthetic
11:55:17.989 ready-functions.js?200226115513:450 Aesthetic
11:55:17.989 ready-functions.js?200226115513:453 has class
11:55:18.801 ready-functions.js?200226115513:448 aesthetic
11:55:18.801 ready-functions.js?200226115513:450 Aesthetic
11:55:18.801 ready-functions.js?200226115513:453 has class
```

**Why is this always saying the class 'selected' is there?**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".popular-tag", function(){
  var popularTag = $(this);
  var popularTagSlug = popularTag.attr('popular-value');
  console.log(popularTagSlug);
  var popularTagName = popularTag.attr('popular-full');
  console.log(popularTagName);

  if (popularTag.hasClass('selected')) {
   console.log('has class');
   popularTag.removeClass('selected');
   popularTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
   popularTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
   popularTag.removeAttr('data-name');
  } else {
   console.log('doesnt have class');
   popularTag.addClass('selected');
   popularTag.addClass('selected-tag');
   popularTag.attr('data-slug', popularTagSlug);
   popularTag.attr('data-name', popularTagName);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popular-tags-selection">

  <div class="popular-tags-selection-title">
   Popular properties
  </div>

  <div id="popular-tags" class="popular-tags">

   <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="aesthetic" popular-full="Aesthetic"><div class="popular-tag-title">Aesthetic</div></div>
   <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="corrosion-resistant" popular-full="Corrosion resistant"><div class="popular-tag-title">Corrosion resistant</div></div>
   <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="hard" popular-full="Hard"><div class="popular-tag-title">Hard</div></div>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Upon adding this snippet into the fiddle, it appears to work. How can I go about troubleshooting this so I can find out why this doesn't operate as planned?

### Edit

(Adding full jQuery to help further troubleshooting) - This code in a nutshell is a ~ dropdown of tags, a couple popular tags, then a div that contains the selected tags from the previously stated two sections. I am then adding functionality that will add and remove the classes on the tags in each of the instances of the tags be it in the tag dropdown, popular tags or the selected tags:

```js
// TAG DROPDOWN TAGS
 $(document).on("click", ".search-tag", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var searchTag = $(this);
  var searchTagSlug = searchTag.attr('value');
  var searchTagName = searchTag.attr('name');

  if (searchTag.hasClass('selected')) {
   searchTag.removeClass('selected');
   searchTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
   searchTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
   searchTag.removeAttr('data-name');
  } else {
   searchTag.addClass('selected');
   searchTag.addClass('selected-tag');
   searchTag.attr('data-slug', searchTagSlug);
   searchTag.attr('data-name', searchTagName);
  }

  var popularTags = $('#popular-tags');
  var alsoPopularTag = popularTags.children('[popular-value=' + searchTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoPopularTag.length) {
   if (alsoPopularTag.hasClass('selected')) {
    alsoPopularTag.removeClass('selected');
    alsoPopularTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
    alsoPopularTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
    alsoPopularTag.removeAttr('data-name');
   } else {
    alsoPopularTag.addClass('selected');
    alsoPopularTag.addClass('selected-tag');
    alsoPopularTag.attr('data-slug', searchTagSlug);
    alsoPopularTag.attr('data-name', searchTagName);
   }
  }

  var selectedTags = $('#selected-tags');
  var alsoSelectedTag = selectedTags.children('[data-selected-tag-slug=' + searchTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoSelectedTag.length) {
   alsoSelectedTag.remove();
  } else {
   selectedTags.prepend('<div class="selected-tag-quick" data-slug="' + searchTagSlug + '" data-name="' + searchTagName + '" data-selected-tag-slug="' + searchTagSlug + '" data-selected-tag-name="' + searchTagName + '"><div class="selected-tag-quick-name">' + searchTagName +'</div></div>');
  }
 });
 // END TAG DROPDOWN TAGS

 // POPULAR TAGS
 $(document).on("click", ".popular-tag", function(){
  var popularTag = $(this);
  var popularTagSlug = popularTag.attr('popular-value');
  console.log(popularTagSlug);
  var popularTagName = popularTag.attr('popular-full');
  console.log(popularTagName);

  if (popularTag.hasClass('selected')) {
   console.log('has class');
   popularTag.removeClass('selected');
   popularTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
   popularTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
   popularTag.removeAttr('data-name');
  } else {
   console.log('doesnt have class');
   popularTag.addClass('selected');
   popularTag.addClass('selected-tag');
   popularTag.attr('data-slug', popularTagSlug);
   popularTag.attr('data-name', popularTagName);
  }

  var searchTags = $('#search-tags-list');
  var alsoSearchTag = searchTags.children('[value=' + popularTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoSearchTag.length) {
   if (alsoSearchTag.hasClass('selected')) {
    alsoSearchTag.removeClass('selected');
    alsoSearchTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
    alsoSearchTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
    alsoSearchTag.removeAttr('data-name');
   } else {
    alsoSearchTag.addClass('selected');
    alsoSearchTag.addClass('selected-tag');
    alsoSearchTag.attr('data-slug', popularTagSlug);
    alsoSearchTag.attr('data-name', popularTagName);
   }
  }

  var selectedTags = $('#selected-tags');
  var alsoSelectedTag = selectedTags.children('[data-selected-tag-slug=' + popularTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoSelectedTag.length) {
   alsoSelectedTag.remove();
  } else {
   selectedTags.prepend('<div class="selected-tag-quick" data-slug="' + popularTagSlug + '" data-name="' + popularTagName + '" data-selected-tag-slug="' + popularTagSlug + '" data-selected-tag-name="' + popularTagName + '"><div class="selected-tag-quick-name">' + popularTagName +'</div></div>');
  }
 });
 // END POPULAR TAGS

 // SELECTED TAGS
 $(document).on("click", ".selected-tag-quick", function(e){
  var selectedTag = $(this);
  var selectedTagSlug = selectedTag.attr('data-selected-tag-slug');
  var selectedTagName = selectedTag.attr('data-selected-tag-name');

  selectedTag.remove();

  var searchTags = $('#search-tags-list');
  var alsoSearchTag = searchTags.children('[value=' + selectedTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoSearchTag.length) {
   if (alsoSearchTag.hasClass('selected')) {
    alsoSearchTag.removeClass('selected');
    alsoSearchTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
    alsoSearchTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
    alsoSearchTag.removeAttr('data-name');
   } else {
    alsoSearchTag.addClass('selected');
    alsoSearchTag.addClass('selected-tag');
    alsoSearchTag.attr('data-slug', selectedTagSlug);
    alsoSearchTag.attr('data-name', selectedTagName);
   }
  }

  var popularTags = $('#popular-tags');
  var alsoPopularTag = popularTags.children('[data-value=' + selectedTagSlug + ']');
  if (alsoPopularTag.length) {
   if (alsoPopularTag.hasClass('selected')) {
    alsoPopularTag.removeClass('selected');
    alsoPopularTag.removeClass('selected-tag');
    alsoPopularTag.removeAttr('data-slug');
    alsoPopularTag.removeAttr('data-name');
   } else {
    alsoPopularTag.addClass('selected');
    alsoPopularTag.addClass('selected-tag');
    alsoPopularTag.attr('data-slug', selectedTagSlug);
    alsoPopularTag.attr('data-name', selectedTagName);
   }
  }
 });
 // END SELECTED TAGS
```

```css
.search-properties {
padding: 50px;
background-color: green;
margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.tags-selection {
margin-right: 20px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.tags-selection-title {
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.search-tags {
max-width: 280px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.search-tags-title {
width: 100%;
min-width: 280px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #007dbe;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.search-tags-dropdown-image {
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-tags-title.open .search-tags-dropdown-image {
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.search-tag {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}
.popular-tags .search-tag {
width: auto;
height: 50px;
}

.search-tags-list {
width: 100%;
max-height: 400px;
background-color: #000041;
border-left: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-right: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #007dbe;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1000;
}

.search-tags-list > div:nth-of-type(n + 2){
border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.search-tag-title {
width: calc((100% - 50px) - 10px);
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}


.search-tags-title .search-tag-title {
color: #007dbe;
}

.search-tags-dropdown {
width: 50px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.search-tags-dropdown-image {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 5px;
}

.tick-box {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-tag.selected .tick-box {
background-color: rgba(112,182,44,1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.search-tag .tick-box:after {
content: '✔';
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-size: 24px;
color: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.search-tag.selected .tick-box:after {
color: #ffffff;
}

.popular-tags-selection {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.popular-tags-selection-title {
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.popular-tags {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.popular-tag {
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 5px;
border: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #007dbe;
cursor: pointer;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.popular-tag.selected-tag {
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
}

#selected-tags {
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#selected-tags:not(:empty) {
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

#selected-tags:not(:empty):before {
content: 'Properties Selected:';
margin-right: 5px;
color: #007dbe;
}

#selected-tags .selected-tag-quick {
height: 50px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
border-radius: 10px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.popular-tag.selected-tag:hover,
#selected-tags .selected-tag-quick:hover {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-properties">
     
  <div class="tags-selection">

   <div class="tags-selection-title">
    Properties
   </div>

   <div id="search-tags" class="search-tags">

    <div id="search-tags-title" class="search-tags-title">
     <div class="search-tag-title">Select Properties</div>
     <div class="search-tags-dropdown"><img src="/wp-content/themes/hubble-space/assets/img/blue-chevvy-right.svg" class="search-tags-dropdown-image" alt="Show Tags List"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="search-tags-list" class="search-tags-list">
     <div class="search-tag" value="abrasion-resistant" name="Abrasion resistant"><div class="search-tag-title">Abrasion resistant</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div><div class="search-tag" value="acoustic" name="Acoustic"><div class="search-tag-title">Acoustic</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div><div class="search-tag" value="aesthetic" name="Aesthetic"><div class="search-tag-title">Aesthetic</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div>
    </div>

   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="popular-tags-selection">

   <div class="popular-tags-selection-title">
    Popular properties
   </div>

   <div id="popular-tags" class="popular-tags">

    <div class="search-tag popular-tag" popular-value="aesthetic" popular-full="Aesthetic"><div class="popular-tag-title">Aesthetic</div></div>

   </div>

  </div>

  <div id="selected-tags"></div>

 </div>
```

### Solved

I have synchronised all of the data attributes to use the same data-attr='' then written a single code block that handles all conditions. Much cleaner and has stopped the conflict:

```js
// TAGS SELECTION
$(document).on("click", "[value]", function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();

 var clickedTag = $(this);
 var clickedTagSlug = clickedTag.attr('value');
 var clickedTagName = clickedTag.attr('full');
 var clickedTags = $('.search-tag[value=' + clickedTagSlug + ']');
 var selectedClickedTag = $('.quick-selected-tag[value=' + clickedTagSlug + ']');
 var selectedTags = $('#selected-tags');

 clickedTags.each(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
   $(this).removeClass('selected');
   $(this).removeClass('selected-tag');
   $(this).removeAttr('data-slug');
   $(this).removeAttr('data-name');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected-tag');
   $(this).attr('data-slug', clickedTagSlug);
   $(this).attr('data-name', clickedTagName);
  }
 });

 if (selectedClickedTag.length) {
  selectedClickedTag.remove();
 } else {
  selectedTags.prepend('<div class="quick-selected-tag" data-slug="' + clickedTagSlug + '" data-name="' + clickedTagName + '" value="' + clickedTagSlug + '" full="' + clickedTagName + '"><div class="quick-selected-tag-name">' + clickedTagName +'</div></div>');
 }
});
// END TAGS SELECTION
```

```css
.search-properties {
padding: 50px;
background-color: green;
margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.tags-selection {
margin-right: 20px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.tags-selection-title {
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.search-tags {
max-width: 280px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.search-tags-title {
width: 100%;
min-width: 280px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #007dbe;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.search-tags-dropdown-image {
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-tags-title.open .search-tags-dropdown-image {
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.search-tag {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}
.popular-tags .search-tag {
width: auto;
height: 50px;
}

.search-tags-list {
width: 100%;
max-height: 400px;
background-color: #000041;
border-left: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-right: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #007dbe;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1000;
}

.search-tags-list > div:nth-of-type(n + 2){
border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.search-tag-title {
width: calc((100% - 50px) - 10px);
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
}


.search-tags-title .search-tag-title {
color: #007dbe;
}

.search-tags-dropdown {
width: 50px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.search-tags-dropdown-image {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 5px;
}

.tick-box {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-tag.selected .tick-box {
background-color: rgba(112,182,44,1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.search-tag .tick-box:after {
content: '✔';
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-size: 24px;
color: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.search-tag.selected .tick-box:after {
color: #ffffff;
}

.popular-tags-selection {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.popular-tags-selection-title {
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.popular-tags {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.popular-tag {
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 5px;
border: 1px solid #007dbe;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #007dbe;
cursor: pointer;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.popular-tag.selected-tag {
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
}

#selected-tags {
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#selected-tags:not(:empty) {
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

#selected-tags:not(:empty):before {
content: 'Properties Selected:';
margin-right: 5px;
color: #007dbe;
}

#selected-tags .selected-tag-quick {
height: 50px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
border-radius: 10px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.popular-tag.selected-tag:hover,
#selected-tags .selected-tag-quick:hover {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-properties">
 
 <div class="tags-selection">

  <div class="tags-selection-title">
   Properties
  </div>

  <div id="search-tags" class="search-tags">

   <div id="search-tags-title" class="search-tags-title">
    <div class="search-tag-title">Select Properties</div>
    <div class="search-tags-dropdown"><img src="/wp-content/themes/hubble-space/assets/img/blue-chevvy-right.svg" class="search-tags-dropdown-image" alt="Show Tags List"></div>
   </div>

   <div id="search-tags-list" class="search-tags-list">
    <div class="search-tag" value="abrasion-resistant" full="Abrasion resistant"><div class="search-tag-title">Abrasion resistant</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div>
    <div class="search-tag" value="acoustic" full="Acoustic"><div class="search-tag-title">Acoustic</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div>
    <div class="search-tag" value="aesthetic" full="Aesthetic"><div class="search-tag-title">Aesthetic</div><div class="tick-box tag-tick-box"></div></div>
   </div>

  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="popular-tags-selection">

  <div class="popular-tags-selection-title">
   Popular properties
  </div>

  <div id="popular-tags" class="popular-tags">

   <div class="search-tag popular-tag" value="aesthetic" full="Aesthetic"><div class="popular-tag-title">Aesthetic</div></div>

  </div>

 </div>

 <div id="selected-tags"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code should work just fine. If you cannot reproduce the problem using just the code you've pasted, it indicates that there's something else being loaded on your page (or your browser plugins/extensions) that's modifying that behavior.

Comment: Any pointers on how I can go about this?

Comment: As it is running on a click and uses the $(this), I cannot comprehend how this can slip outside the scope of the element it has clicked in order to check for the class?

Comment: After the page load. Have you tried running this in console `$('.popular-tag').hasClass('selected')`? What does it shows? How about expecting the element in the debug, does it shows any **visible** selected tag?

Comment: Putting that into the console with a change to the $ -> jQuery. It returns false.

Comment: You can (1) inspect your DOM to see if anything else is making changes to your element(s) and (2) remove all other scripts and progressively add them back until you can reproduce the issue: then you'll find the culprit.

Comment: It may be worth me putting my full list of functions I have angled towards these particular elements... Please see the edit at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I have added the snippet and you can now see the issue, Aesthetic is one example what utilises all the areas where tags are used, if you click from the dropdown, it works adding and removing. If you click elsewhere it breaks... @Terry